# Flutter - How to display For-loop results on screen

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

This is probably very basic but I can't figure it out. I want to display my for-loop results on the app screen. trying to use the Text widget method with the variable `_result` doesn't bring the results onto the screen. Initially, on the app start, the screen only shows **0** but it would not change after clicking on the button. the print command shows me the proper results on the run console but these results do not come on the screen. I've tried many things that I learned over time like changing `int` to `String` but to no avail, it's still not working.  I've done a lot of google searches but I still can't figure it out. what am I missing? please help.

here's the full code:

```
//import 'dart:html';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  var sum = 25;
  var _result = 0;

  //static int _result = 0;

  //String resultS;
  //= _result.toString();

  void callForLoop() {
    print('The sum of ' '$sum' ' with 5 digits');
    for (int z = 1; z <= 9; z++) {
      for (int y = 1; y <= 9; y++) {
        for (int x = 1; x <= 9; x++) {
          for (int w = 1; w <= 9; w++) {
            for (int v = 1; v <= 9; v++) {
              if (z + y + x + w + v == sum) {
                if (z < y) {
                  if (y < x) {
                    if (x < w) {
                      if (w < v) {
                        _result = (z + y + x + w + v);
                        print('$z + $y + $x + $w + $v');

                        //style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                        continue;
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //resultS = _result.toString();
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            body: Center(
                child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
          Text('$_result'),
          //style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
          Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 0),
              child: RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () => callForLoop(),
                child: Text('Call For Loop'),
                textColor: Colors.white,
                color: Colors.lightBlue,
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 12, 12, 12),
              )),
        ]))));
  }
}
```

Comment: Make the widget `StatelessWidget` and call setState method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your StatelessWidget to a StatefulWidget. If using Android Studio, highlight the class name, right-click on it, and select "Convert to StatefulWidget". Once it has been converted, wrap the line of code where you assign _result a new value with the setState() function like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  var sum = 25;
  var _result = 0;

  String _display = "";
  //static int _result = 0;

  //String resultS;
  //= _result.toString();

  void callForLoop() {
    print('The sum of ' '$sum' ' with 5 digits');
    for (int z = 1; z <= 9; z++) {
      for (int y = 1; y <= 9; y++) {
        for (int x = 1; x <= 9; x++) {
          for (int w = 1; w <= 9; w++) {
            for (int v = 1; v <= 9; v++) {
              if (z + y + x + w + v == sum) {
                if (z < y) {
                  if (y < x) {
                    if (x < w) {
                      if (w < v) {
                        _display = '$z + $y + $x + $w + $v';

                        //style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                        continue;
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //resultS = _result.toString();
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            body: Center(
                child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
          Text(_display),
          //style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
          Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 0),
              child: RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () => callForLoop(),
                child: Text('Call For Loop'),
                textColor: Colors.white,
                color: Colors.lightBlue,
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 12, 12, 12),
              )),
        ]))));
  }
}
```

The setState() function calls the build() method and redraws the widgets on the screen. Therefore, when you assign _result a new value in the setState() method I showed you, it should update the Text widget with the new value.

Comment: ok, it works but still doesn't give me the results that I want. it only gives me the sum of all the numbers. I actually want it to display on the screen the whole statement. for example. "1 + 4 + 5 + 7 + 8". just like this 'print('$z + $y + $x + $w + $v');'  does on the console.

Comment: You can create a new String under where you are declaring the _result variable. Whenever you are calling setState(), you can set that variable to '$z + $y + $x + $w + $v'. After this make sure that your text widget is displaying this String variable you just created and not the _result one. So for your text widget, just change the text value from _result to whatever the new variable you created is called